# Is it possible to call a lein-plugin function from a lein-repl?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I want to control a number of lein-plugins (lein-cljs build, lein-aws, lein-beanstalk) from my lein repl. Is there a way to do this?

For example, I want to be able to call

plugin/src/leiningen/cljsbuild.clj: once

from the repl -- however, I apparently can't (require 'leiningen.cljsbuild) into my lein repl.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this addresses what you are actually trying to do, but do you know about lein interactive mode?  EDIT: Since lein interactive doesn't exist in the new version of lein, the solution may be in some use of [jark](http://icylisper.in/jark/started.html).  Jark has an interactive mode and a plugin to use lein, so it may be possible to issue both lein commands and call clojure functions from a single interactive prompt.

Comment: Not until just now. Is there someway to have "interactive mode" and "repl mode" merged as one? I want to both be able to do the commands from interactive mode -- yet also have a clojure repl.

Comment: Actually lein interactive is phased out in lein 2.

Comment: Does this mean it's integrated into lein repl -- or completely unavailable?

Comment: I heard a rumor that there may be a plan to replace lein interactive with jark (http://icylisper.in/jark/).

Answer (score 0):

The [Vinyasa](https://github.com/zcaudate/vinyasa) library claims to provide this functionality. At the time of this writing, `vinyasa.lein` is [broken](https://github.com/zcaudate/vinyasa/issues/28), but it may be fixed in the near future.